# Using an image inside template string in Storybook

Tags: angular, storybook

I am trying to use an image inside a storybook story. In the original app it has an image inserted dynamically and i need to reproduce that in storybook.

I have managed to get the image into storybook using required (import just threw errors), however i cant figure out how i then add it to the template string.

Can someone help?

Here's what i have:

```
var imageFile = require('./static/defaultfeeditem.jpg');
const image = {
  src: imageFile,
  alt: 'my image',
};


.add('Individual item', () => (
{
  template:
    `
    <!-- *ngFor="let recipe of recipes" no longer used since component was introduced.-->
    <ion-card class="ion-no-margin feedCard">
      <!-- loop though all recipies in recipies.page.ts module.-->
      <ion-img class="feedCard__img" [src]=imageFile"></ion-img><!-- [isPropertybinding] in this context-->
      <div class="feedCard__img--circles">
        <ion-icon name="radio-button-off"></ion-icon>
        <ion-icon name="radio-button-off"></ion-icon>
        <ion-icon name="radio-button-off"></ion-icon>
      </div>
    </ion-card>
    <div class="feedCard__label">
      <ion-label> {{ feedItem.title }} </ion-label>
      <!-- string interprelation -->
      <ion-label><strong> {{ feedItem.distance }}km </strong></ion-label> <!-- string interprelation -->
    </div>
    `,
      props: {
      },
    }))
```

Comment: what about `[src]=${imageFile}` ?

Comment: That leads to it saying there's an unclosed element/tag. I guess because src is supposed to be followed by "" and its not getting what it wants.

If i wrap it in quotes it gives this error: 
Template parse errors: Parser Error: Unexpected token '0.49164563' at column 29 in [static/media/defaultfeeditem.49164563.jpg] in ng:///DynamicModule/DynamicComponent.html@4:39

<ion-img class="feedCard__img" [ERROR ->][src]='static/media/defaultfeeditem.49164563.jpg'